# Controller Value is not showing in view Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In the view `{{phonenumber}}` value is not updating. But When I enter digits alert is working properly inside the controller.

> **Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('PosController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.phonenumberFromDial = "";
        $scope.phonenumber = "";
        $scope.updatePhoneNumber = function(id) {
        $scope.phonenumberFromDial=id;
        $scope.phonenumber =$scope.phonenumber+$scope.phonenumberFromDial;
        if($scope.phonenumber.length > 9) {
            console.log("Log phonenumber: " + $scope.phonenumberFromDial);
            alert('Here the Number: '+ $scope.phonenumber);
        } 
});
```

> **View**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PosController" class="panel" >
    <div class="input-group col-xs-4">  
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Telefono</button>
        </div><!-- /btn-group -->        

        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PosController">
            <input  id="phonenumber" class="form-control" ng-model="phonenumber" />
            <!--<input type="text" id="phonenumber" ng-model="myModel" ng-keyup="(myModel.length >= 3) && myFunction()" class="form-control" data-inputmask='"mask": "(999) 999-9999"' data-mask>-->
        </div>

        <div class="input-group-btn" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Cliente</button>
        </div><!-- /btn-group -->
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PosController">\
            <input type="text" id="cliente"  class="form-control"  value="{{phonenumber}}"> 
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: You should first remove the several `ng-controller="PosController"` from the code and only leave one at the upmost div. Also remove all the descendant `ng-app="myApp"` from every div except the upmost.

Comment: You could also use ng-model="phonenumber" to use 2-way data binding. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: to where should I add ng-model?

Comment: joaumg-I removed those but still no value is passing to the view

Comment: You are missing parentheses in your controller. And if you remove the extra ng-app and ng-controllers like @joaumg mentioned, it will work. I verified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some observations :**

- remove unecessary multiple ng-controller="PosController" and ng-app="myApp" from the code and leave with only one at the top.
- use `ng-model="phonenumber"` instead of `value="{{phonenumber}}"` to perform two way data binding.

**Working demo :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('PosController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.phonenumberFromDial = "";
        $scope.phonenumber = "";
        $scope.updatePhoneNumber = function(id) {
        $scope.phonenumberFromDial=id;
        $scope.phonenumber =$scope.phonenumber+$scope.phonenumberFromDial;
        if($scope.phonenumber.length > 9) {
            console.log("Log phonenumber: " + $scope.phonenumberFromDial);
            alert('Here the Number: '+ $scope.phonenumber);
        } 
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PosController" class="panel" >
    <div class="input-group col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" id="phonenumber" class="form-control" ng-model="phonenumber"/>
        <div class="input-group-btn" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updatePhoneNumber(phonenumber)">Cliente</button>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="cliente" class="form-control"  ng-model="phonenumber">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.Actually I updated phone number using dial pad.So is not in this view.I used another view to update phone number.So I need to update that number at the same time in this view.

Comment: Can you please explain your exact requirement or you can also provide fiddle or plnkr link here.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/f6Uh8yUxVFV9d0minSMt?p=preview
here the plnkr.but now it is not work.but you can get idea what i am going to say.here 2 view files.one for dial numbers and other for showing.in my code dialed numbers updated in controller.but that is not view in 2 view file.Hope you get understand my prob.

Comment: Thank you I found that solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you're missing. First of the all, as suggested in comment, you only need to declare `ng-app` and `ng-controller` once in the HTML with `np-app` on the top-most level. Secondly, you bind the scope data to the HTML using `ng-model` inside a input field, or `{{phonenumber}}` in HTML. Third, you forgot to close the controller with an ending parenthesis.

Here is a working demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('PosController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.phonenumberFromDial = "";
        $scope.phonenumber = "";
      $scope.updatePhoneNumber = function(id) {
          $scope.phonenumberFromDial=id;
          $scope.phonenumber =$scope.phonenumber+$scope.phonenumberFromDial;
          if($scope.phonenumber.length > 9) {
            console.log("Log phonenumber: " + $scope.phonenumberFromDial);
            alert('Here the Number: '+ $scope.phonenumber);
          } 
     }
     });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="panel" >
  <div class="input-group col-xs-4" ng-controller="PosController">  
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Telefono</button>
    </div><!-- /btn-group -->        
    <div>
        <input  id="phonenumber" class="form-control" ng-model="phonenumber" />
        <!--<input type="text" id="phonenumber" ng-model="myModel" ng-keyup="(myModel.length >= 3) && myFunction()" class="form-control" data-inputmask='"mask": "(999) 999-9999"' data-mask>-->
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-btn" >
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Cliente</button>
    </div><!-- /btn-group -->
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="cliente"  class="form-control"  ng-model="phonenumber"> 
    </div>
    <span>Phone#: {{phonenumber}}</span>
     <div>
      Dial: <input type="text" id="cliente"  class="form-control"  ng-model="phonenumberFromDial"> 
    </div>
     <div class="input-group-btn" >
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updatePhoneNumber(phonenumberFromDial)">Update phone#</button>
    </div><!-- /btn-group -->
  </div> 
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.Actually I updated phone number using dial pad.So is not in this view.I used another view to update phone number.So I need to update that number at the same time in this view.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/f6Uh8yUxVFV9d0minSMt?p=preview here the plnkr.but now it is not work.but you can get idea what i am going to say.here 2 view files.one for dial numbers and other for showing.in my code dialed numbers updated in controller.but that is not view in 2 view file.Hope you get understand my prob

Comment: Thank you I found that solution.